# ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: sql, mysql, chave-estrangeira

Olá Estou tentando adicionar uma chave estrangeira à uma tabela porém recebo o erro 1215. Já chequei os atributos e todos estão compatíveis, o campo carteira é uma chave primária, não compreendo porque não é possível adicionar a chave.

[image: Tabela Acionistas]

[image: Tabela Carteira]

[image: Inserção da FK]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
ALTER TABLE `acoes_db`.`Carteira` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `carteira_fk`
  FOREIGN KEY (`ID`)
  REFERENCES `acoes_db`.`Acionistas` (`Carteira`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o próprio nome sugere a `Foreign Key` (chave estrangeira) é a(s) coluna(s) que identifica(m) o pai em a partir da tabela filha.

Voce está tentando adicionar a FK no pai referência do a tabela filha (o cenário oposto).

Tenta fazer assim:

```
ALTER TABLE `acoes_db`.`Acionistas` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `carteira_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Carteira`)
    REFERENCES `acoes_db`.`Carteira` (`ID`);
```